# Create external forest domain trust on Active Directory 2012 R2

Tags: dns, external, trust

I tried to create external forest domain using the below steps and seeing exception while I validate the trust from any of the domains.

I am trying to setup external trust between two active directory domains (domain1.demo.com called as DOMAIN1 on computer AD-RESOURCE) and (domain2.addemo.co.uk called as DOMAIN2 on computer WIN-7ABCDEFG). 
The expectation is to be:
Domain-wide authentication, Non-Transitive, External, Outgoing only from the domain dtpad.addemo.co.uk

On the domain, DOMAIN2:

1. Open Active Directory Domains and Trusts
2. On the domain, Right click and open Trusts
3. Click on Add Trust
4. Provided the computer name: AD-RESOURCE, Still asked me to provide realm trust or domain name. So, I provided Domain name: DOMAIN1
5. Trust with a Windows domain, Specified domain: DOMAIN1
6. Select External Trust
7. Select one way: Outgoing
8. Create trust for the following: This domain only
9. Scope of authentication for users from DOMAIN1: Domain-wide authentication
10. Trust Password
11. Ready to create the trust
    a.  This domain: domain2.addemo.co.uk
    b.  Specified domain: DOMAIN1
    c.  Direction: Outgoing: Users in the specified domain can authenticate in the local domain
    d.  Trust Type: External
    e.  Transitive: No
    f.  Outgoing trust authentication level: Domain-wide authentication
    g.  Sides of trust: Create the trust for this domain only
12. Next – Trust relationship created successfully
13. Do you want to confirm the outgoing trust? – Yes, confirm the outgoing trust
14. Completing the New Trust Wizard
    You have successfully completed the new trust wizard, but the newly created relationship cannot be confirmed for the following reasons:
    i.  The verification of outgoing trust failed with the following errors: The trust password verification failed with error 1787: 
    The security database on the server does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship.Before this trust can function, 
    it must also be created in the other domain. Ensure the same trust password is used in both domains.

I am trying to execute the above steps as Domain Admin.

Regards,
Tejo.